Title each code chunk with the language in that code chunk
I am writing a manual for some work stuff in Quarto. Some of the pages will include both R and Python. I am wondering if there is a way to automatically label each code chunk with the language in that code chunk. I am currently trying it manually via title and #| label: R but neither are outputting anything.
```{python, title="Python"}

1 + 1
```

```{r, title="R"}
#| label: R

1 + 1
```

As you can see below, neither actually appear on the rendered HTML.

I would prefer each cell to have the language labelled something like this:

The exact location within the cell does not matter to me.
Automated would be preferred, but manual is completely acceptable as well.
I am using RStudio with R version 4.4.1, reticulate version 1.38.0, and Python 3.12.4.

The fenced echo option might get close, though not fully.

@I_O well it's not pretty but it's something! We'll see if someone else finds something that looks better, but if not, I encourage you to post it as an answer so I can credit you

Not really what it's meant for, but you also could use Code Filename.

Seems as though you could also hack the code-filename attribute (AFAICT Quarto doesn't actually do anything with the named file, so this would give you a different formatting option.) Hacking the CSS seems like a much bigger challenge ...

@Jan, jinx .....

@Jan that's actually quite nice looking! I'll post what it looks like in my question since I don't think I can here in the comments

@gabagool, please don't add answers as an update to your question. Instead, please post your own answer including this information (this is encouraged).

Using CSS
Use this CSS code at the top of your document (add further CSS styling as desired):
```{css, echo=FALSE}
code.sourceCode.r::before{content:'R'; float:right}
code.sourceCode.python::before{content:'Python'; float:right}
}
```

```{python}
1 + 1
```

```{r}
1 + 1
```


using Javascript
just keeping this initial approach for completeness
As you're rendering to HTML, you can use Javascript to manipulate, i.a. the code cells. The following boilerplate shows how to select all HTML nodes of class ".cell-code", query a custom data attribute from their parent (let's call it 'language') and insert a paragraph with the language attribute as content. I set the style attribute as a quick-and-dirty solution, but you could also set a custom CSS class to manipulate the style for the whole doc in one place.

add a (custom) language attribute to your code chunk:

```{r, language = 'R'}
1 + 1
```


put this Javascript snippet at the bottom of your doc:

```{js, echo = FALSE}
document.querySelectorAll('.cell-code')
  .forEach(codeBlock => {
     const ele = document.createElement("p")
     ele.innerText = codeBlock.parentNode.dataset.language
     ele.setAttribute('style', 'float:right;margin:.5em;font-size:.8rem')
     codeBlock.insertBefore(ele, codeBlock.childNodes[0])
  })
```

output:

